# How to find or add build.sbt file to existing Eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt

I need the ability to parse XML files in Scala for a regression modelling project of mine. It seems that  there is no longer a scala.xml package ready form the get-go so we need it externally. Solution seems to be the project scala.xml from GitHub: https://github.com/scala/scala-xml

Thing is, in order for me to get the JAR file to Eclipse it seems I need to use sbt. I have sbt installed but the regression modelling project was originally made in Eclipse by `File -> New -> Scala Project`.

Last time I used sbt was when I tried to get ScalaFX to work in Eclipse. I then understood why they changed the name from Simple Build Tools to Scala Build Tools. It was pure hell to get the JAR file (which I did not get by using sbt).

The only way to get the library `scala.xml` in Scala version 2.12 is via sbt. So now the situation is that I need to make modifications to `sbt.build` file which doesn't (?) exist in the Eclipse project as the project wasn't made using sbt.  How do I do this?

Comment: It's not completely true that _SBT_ is the only way to get the _JAR_ file: any tool that accesses _Maven_ or _Ivy_ repositories can be used, but _SBT_ is the simplest, believe it or not. Last time I looked at [_ScalaIDE_](http://scala-ide.org/) (based on _Eclipse_), it didn't support _SBT_ builds. A far, _far_ better IDE for _Scala_ IMHO is [_IntelliJ IDEA_](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), with the _Scala_ plugin, which integrates _SBT_ superbly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to my own question for anyone having this same problem:
You can make a  Git project into a JAR file really easily. What you need is git commands and sbt installed. Here's what you do

i) Open up any directory. Preferably make a new directory with descriptive name.

ii) Go to the Git project you want, click the green box "Clone or download" and copy the url.

iii) Open console, go to the directory you want the project and type git clone _ where _ is the url of the project.

iv) Once the project is cloned open it with console.

v) Type sbt and wait until sbt sets everything up.

vi) Depending on the Scala version you want to use you can do it now after compiling.

vii) Type compile and wait for the sbt to compile.

viii) Once compiling is done type package and you have the JAR file in the projects target directory. After compiling path is shown in the console.